# unsure what mountrender means in vue profiling

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, mount, devtools, vue-devtools

I have the vue-profiling report below:

[image: Analysis]

AS you can see mountRender takes an insane amount of time. I want to cut this down. How can I do so? Is there anyway I can see what is taking mountRender so long and what the breakdown is of MountRender.

Comment: That is the part that actually creates the DOM and paints it on screen